# Handle response from SQL query in Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.1.0 for .NET

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-sql

I have an Elasticsearch cluster, which e.g. contains an index called `persons`. I want to query the documents of the index using the SQL API of Elasticsearch. When using the REST API of Elasticsearch via Kibana everything works fine:

```
POST /_sql?format=csv
{
  "query": "SELECT * FROM persons"
}
```

However, I want to execute this query within a .NET Web API project. Therefore, I am using a .NET client for Elasticsearch (Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.1.0). I have already set up and configured the client, which worked fine. Now I am trying to execute the same query as mentioned above using the Elasticsearch .NET client like this:

```
var response = await _elasticsearchClient.Sql
                     .QueryAsync(q => q.Query("SELECT * FROM persons"));
```

When executing this query, Elasticsearch returns a valid response. However, this response seems to contain no results (even though the index `persons` contains documents). To be more precise, I can only access the returned columns and the cursor but not the returned rows.

Am I missing something or does the Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.1.0 client not fully support the SQL API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that this was a bug related to code generation from the Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.1.0 .NET client. For more details see [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/response-from-sql-query-does-not-contain-rows-elastic-clients-elasticsearch-8-1-0-net) discussion. This bug is addressed by [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/7663) on GitHub and will be fixed in version 8.1.1.